# How to make pattern to image in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var image = new fabric.Image(img, {
  crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
});
var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
  source: patternSource,
  repeat: 'no-repeat'
});
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: image.width,
  height: image.height,
  fill: pattern
});

rect.cloneAsImage(rectImage => {
  const maskFilter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendImage({
    image: image,
    mode: 'mask'
  });
  rectImage.filters.push(maskFilter)
  rectImage.applyFilters();
  canvas.add(rectImage);
  canvas.renderAll();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<img id="patternSource" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAACrElEQVR42u2Xz2sTQRSAX8VSb1K8iNqKooJH2Ux6Ksn+iPQqxZMIehJB0do/IMhmQWsvHr2KSEGk0tSLIoWIYNUKij20F2/N7iaUZnYT0kYzzhMKs0HDJiTdLcwHDwKZSd63781LBiQSSW9JZdkhzfKm1Rz9mjZp/W9YdEU3vXv4HsQZ40FtNG36q5rls//Ej4tmbSS2T15Mvp3ExOPmEMQNbBtMMEyoljcFcQN7PqyAlqNfIG7gYQ0tYNIaxA1MrJPY3wImbUqBKAXSFv0tBSIVMOkvKRDtGKWN/T6FdqRAxFNoWwpEPIXqUqBT6ALU/UVgu8GW4GD3f6f9TRDYNJTDrk7YbtiqUumHwIYoUJuHERDAS0r4CvgFECgbY+cFAR7KT+g1POmCKFDNw6WggHc3fBtVb4CAoyauBgXIG+g1Xh5mRAGah6cggBd11fK/h7lOprIs0H6uRl6KAo5O7kOv4QmPiwJ4Jqqv4FiwCtXjvD2+tRmfK6kZ/ygI2HritK0rDVGgrClJ6DWMwYC/AGuCBMYcIC2V0CzvjmbRz3j3xUjn6CfeYreUJ2wQkGD75INPX1mFfsEFrrcIYCvdhC4paWQakxajpJMr0C9YFg54i7AsClRmh9/xnr0NHcInzZStk2aLwAcGMAD9pPIazvFKVDD5rdnhJeHLX5RTyRPQHpz5o66emMc9wdlPtvA8wF7Aq2BUHh1525qEo5JtR1WeOXpickO9cJIpyuD6xJmhYiZ5ytWSl3mlnuOaf+2zDaLDXmJrSgZ/MYVEugo+gSh+FkSBa4yd5Ul87DZ5XpFl/AyIEjzYjkau8WqshU2cr13HPbgX4gJOD97n465GZlyVvC9mSKloKI2iTnbwNT+gBX54H+IaXAtxJzE3ycSAFqSAFJACUkAikXD+AHj5/wx2o5osAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
<img id="img" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACQAAAAkCAQAAABLCVATAAABJklEQVR4Ae3VPYrbUBRA4a+RJ1VSJswvGG8mhYsswRhtxT/YmNEuhtEiAmpcJjBJOQsYyyBMsF0qXcjDjNF7pAnJOd0tTqN3r/yLfPCsFfrsvUje+ao91RdvRfBGpX3Fzy6c4UKh0Ua6U+gJKLSJFgKa5FAjoE23W6hRWpp4UKeHNnIZgMzIS0rom1shXHqKDW3cgoHC2tq9PriyiQvl4JPjr8nBEIxjQo0MA8dguneHTN09VL7ySBfgsXtoCdYnoQpMu4cmZ0Oz7qEHcH8SmoOye6iWoe8QTH+4QWYb8/lHYGj/W+YjyOPe0YtLcGehUpm7Adfq2BV5coWQa9/TlnYcLG2uTj8jtUdTM6VtxBlJNGCXnGn+1PFfCegl/Y4aKz1/Lf/5CShXgVKz4A8DAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
/>
```

When pattern is no-repeat, the uncovered area of image is black. But the transparent should be the right color. can this to be solved? Or is there any way to make image clipped by another alpha image?

More detail: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/5018